# Parsing characters with parsec

Tags: beginner, haskell, parsec

I am trying to parse escape sequences as well as plain characters. Can this be made more succinct?

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Char
import Numeric
import Text.Parsec hiding ((<|>))

echar :: Parsec String () Char
echar = (char '\\' >>
         ((char 'b' >> return '\b')
          <|> (char 'f' >> return '\f')
          <|> (char 'n' >> return '\n')
          <|> (char 'r' >> return '\r')
          <|> (char 't' >> return '\t')
          <|> (char 'u' >> count 4 hexDigit >>= return . chr . fst . head . readHex)
          <|> (char 'v' >> return '\v')
          <|> (noneOf "u")))
        <|> noneOf "\\"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cut down on the repetitive elements with a local function binding.

```
echar =
  let
    yield :: Char -> Char -> Parsec String () Char
    yield c d = char c >> return d
  in
    (char '\\' >>
       (  yield 'b' '\b'
      <|> yield 'f' '\f'
       -- ...
```

Then perhaps cut out the repeated applications with a fold.

```
import Data.Foldable

-- ...
  in
    (char '\\' >>
       (  (asum . map (uncurry yield) $ [('b', '\b'), ('f', '\f') -- ...
      <|> (char 'u' -- ...
```

I'm not sure you need the `Numeric` import either, I would write that line as—

```
char 'u' >> count 4 hexDigit >>= return . chr . read . ("0x" ++)
```

And then to tie it all together with a bow.

```
import Control.Applicative        ((<|>))
import Data.Char                  (chr)
import Data.Foldable              (asum)
import Text.Parsec         hiding ((<|>))

echar :: Parsec String () Char
echar =
  let
    escapeCharacters = [('b', '\b'), ('f', '\f'), ('r', '\r'), ('t', '\t'), ('v', '\v')]

    yield :: Char -> Char -> Parsec String () Char
    yield c d = char c >> return d
  in
    (char '\\' >>
       (  (asum . map (uncurry yield) $ escapeCharacters)
      <|> (char 'u' >> count 4 hexDigit >>= return . chr . read . ("0x" ++))
      <|> (noneOf "u")
       )
    ) <|> noneOf "\\"
```

Comment: thanks. Why do you `uncurry` your `yield` rather than making it accept a pair right away?

Comment: 1) Curried functions are the default. 2) You might raise `yield` to the top-level and use it elsewhere, where the uncurried version doesn't make sense. 3) It just feels right.